# Volume of solid revolution about $x$-axis limits

Tags: integration, volume

Question:
Find the volume of solid formed by revolving the
region bounded by the given function $f(x)$:

$$ Y= 3 – x ;$$ about the $x-$axis.

How do I find the upper and lower limits of integration ?

Comment: Please show your work.

Comment: $y=3-x$ is a lineare function, for $x=0$ we get $3$ and for $y=0$ we get also $3$

Comment: Actually, this is the question given. I wrote it as it is. I know how to apply the formula, I just have no idea how to get the limits.

Comment: First of all, use the disk method. The upper limit of integration is going to be $3$ because $3-x=0\implies x=3$. That's the number where the line $3-x$ crosses the x-axis. The lower limit of integration—no idea. It's not entirely clear from your question what it should be. It is poorly formed, I would say.

Comment: You need a 3rd element to bound a region when two elements are non-parallel straight lines. A very poorly written question.